# Twitter bot coded in python

Tags: python, twitter

I want to code a Twitter bot in python. I want the Twitter bot to flip a coin whenever the user asks it for and keep track of how many times they’ve flipped the coin and how many times they received heads and tails.

I honestly don’t know where to begin I’m new to python, and i wanted to code this bot and was wondering if anyone could code it for me so I can see how they coded it and learn from the code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not the place to come to have code written for you. Please show what you've tried so that folks can assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tweepy which is a python library for Twitter API. You can read the docs here- https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/.
Examples are also available.

You'll need a Twitter Developer Account first to get access to the API.

You can use python's random module to simulate coin flip.

Previous data can be stored in a database. Mongodb Atlas is a good option that you can look at.